# System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to render the following in a MVC view with a nullable DateTime(DateTime?), but I got **"System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value"**.  When the value is not null, show the time part (13:15:00) of the date time string (01/01/2014 13:15:00). What is happening?  Thanks.

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Task.Scheduled_Time.Value, "{0:t}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.Value`.

When using the HTML helper methods you need to tell the helper which property you want to use (and what it's type is).

If you say

```
model => model.Task.Scheduled_Time
```

You're saying: "Get the model and create an editor for whatever Scheduled_Time is."

If you say

```
model => model.Task_Scheduled_Time.Value
```

You're saying: "Get the model and create an editor for the property of the value of Scheduled_Time."

If `Scheduled_Time` isn't set (that is: it's null) then `.Value` is nothing and so the property you're trying to select isn't really accessible.

Comment: ok, but it is showing the long DateTime string.  I need to show either date part or time part of the record field. Thanks.